# checking for element present or not using Selenium WebDriver page factory?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Checking for elements with **findElements** using normal WebDriver method is easy like:

```
boolean exists = driver.findElements( By.id("...") ).size() != 0
```

Elements initialized by **Page Factory** are like:

```
@FindBy(name = "filter")
private WebElement filterText;
```

But how can we check in our page that this element is present on the page or not ??

Comment: which binding you are using with `selenium-webdriver` ?

Comment: @Babai: i am using java with the selenium-webdriver

Comment: @vincebowdren assert might just fail the testcase, what i want is, to take a decision based on the element is present on the page or not

Comment: @VidurOberoi I know only Ruby..sorry then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's something i came up with:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement we)
    {  
        try {

            we.getTagName();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            flag = 1;
        }   
       if (flag == 1)
            return true;  
       else
           return false;
    }
```

which is pretty basic but effective way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

The [isDisplayed()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed%28%29) method should do the job:

```java
if (filterText.isDisplayed()) {
    filterText.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: yes, it will get the job done, but sometimes there are elements which are present but are hidden at that particular point of time !!
this wont capture that, i came up with something, have a look at it 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18145746/2043083

Comment: It will only work when the element is on the page. If not, it will return an exception!